# Changing UFT working directory

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I recently had a situation where the application under test was not installed in Program Files or Program Files (x86).

When I launched that application from UFT it complained about not being able to find a ddl file and in the error trace it seemed to be looking for that ddl file not in the application installation directory rather in the UFT installation directory.

The problem was how to change the working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to change the working directory.

1. From the Record and Run settings.

   In the record and run settings dialog box give the application path and the working directory. When the application is launched UFT will refer to the correct working directory.
2. Using Code to change working directory

```html
'Change working directory
    Set objWrkDir = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    objWrkDir.CurrentDirectory = "AUT install path" 
    'Launch application 
    SystemUtil.Run "AUT executable path"
```

Answer (score 0):

As for every process, the child processes are spawned having, as current (working) directory, the current directory of the parent process. In this case it would be the WorkingDir of UFT.

Depending on how you launch your application from *UFT* there are many ways to change the working directory, the simplest is to use **SystemUtil.Run** and as the third param you can provide the WorkingDir.